# Define a variable not explained

Tags: laravel

Sorry for the dumb question but can anyone please tell me how to define a variable in very simple terms? I have struggled for several months with "undefined variable" errors. Are variables stored in `config`? Or maybe in `routes`?

I have a database with a `customers` table. When I put this on my view home page `{{$customers->name}}` I get `Undefined variable: customers`.

Fine. So how and where do I define a variable. I would have thought it WAS defined given that the database table is literally called `customers`. Ugh!

My model file `Customer.php`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customer extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'phone'];

    public function address()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(CustomerAddress::class);
    }

    public function purchases()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(CustomerPurchase::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Undefined variable` means the variable does not exist and the reasons for your case is, you did not pass it in the view.

Usually, to get the `customers` records from the database to your views, you can do it in several ways:

1. Query it prior to loading your view then pass it to your views:

```
//doing it in the controller

//create a controller: php artisan make:controller CustomerController

<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

use App\Customer;     //Dont forget to import your Customer model 

class CustomerController extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $customers = Customer::get();   //this will fetch the customer using your mdoel

        return view('customer', ['customers' => $customers]);  //this will pass the records to the view
    }
}

//then in your routes/web.php:

Route::get('/customers', 'CustomerController@index'); //when you go to your application/customers in the browser, it will go to the controller and return the view with the records.

//OR you can skip the controllers and do it in the routes/web.php directly as what @jitesh jose mentioned.
```

2. Query straight into your view (Not really recommended, but sometimes you just need to make it work)

In your customer.blade.php

```
@php
$customers = \App\Customer::get();
@endphp

<ul>
@foreach($customers as $customer)
    <li>{{$customer->name}}</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

My advice, try to watch a few basic Laravel videos so that you will understand the flow of the request and response.

Answer (score 0):

If your model name is `Customer`,laravel automatically pick the table name as `customers`.Otherwise you have to use your desired table name in Model as follows.

```
 protected $table = 'customers_table';
```

In your `web.php`

```
 Route::get('/home',function () {
  $customers = DB::table('customers_table')->get();
  OR
  $customers = Customer::get();

  return view('welcome')->with('customers',$customers);
 });
```

You can use`$customers` in `welcome.blade.php` as

```
 @foreach($customers as $customer)
  {{$customer->name}}
 @endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you so much. So variables are defined within the model file. Wow, I've been trying to find that answer for weeks!!!

Comment: Updated my question, my model is called Customer so shouldn't ```{{$customer->name}}``` work?

Comment: you have to pass values to view..view can't access database..

Comment: I don't understand. Which is crazy as I have been learning to code for 2 months all day everyday and I STILL don't know simple things. How do I 'pass a value'.?

Comment: How do you learn? I can't use the Laravel documentation as it's way too complicated. Online courses are fine, until something doesn't work then you are lost. University? I just find I am stuck now.

Comment: So in that controller function pass a variable with values to view.

Comment: Yes, in my routes I have a route for the view, I only have a single page ```welcome```. I place the code ```{{$customer->name}} ``` on the welcome page and I find it is ```an undefined variable```.

Comment: Updated answer...try

Comment: Thank you, I did everything you suggested and still get ```Undefined variable: customers ```

Comment: It's OK, I really appreciate the help but I think I need to find a course or something as I am really missing some basics. I always have undefined variables and have never once solved this issue. Back to basics for me I think!